# File name multiple extensions order

Tags: linux, unix, filenames

I want to create some bash scripts. They're actually going to be build scripts for Scala, so I'm going to identify them with my own .bld extension. They will be a sort of sub type of a shell script. Hence I want them to be easily recognised as a shell script. Should I call them

ProjectA.bld.sh //or

ProjectA.sh.bld

Edit: My natural inclination would be to go for the former but .tar.gz files seem to follow the latter naming convention.

Comment: The extension in UNIX doesn't really matter, it is used more as a way to identify the files easier. Normally shell scripts are `.sh`, but it really depends on you and how will be best for you to identify them. Just make sure they can be executed, the rest are details.

Comment: I would say that *some* folks like to put `.sh` at the end of a shell script, but it really doesn't make sense to do that.  You could easily replace the functionality of a shell script with a script in some other language -- should its filename then change?  Just name things for what they are or what they do.  "Extensions" are a DOSism. :)

Answer (score 1):

A shell script doesn't mind what you call it.
It just needs to be..

- executable (chmod +x)
- in your path
- contain a "shebang" as it's first line `#!/bin/sh`

The shebang determines which program is used to execute your script.

Comment: Exactly.  Except that in this case, it would be `#!/bin/bash` per the question.

Comment: It doesn't strictly *need* points 2 and 3. (And there are ways to get around point 1.)

Answer (score 1):

Call it `ProjectA.bld.sh` (or preferably `buildProjectA.sh`).

The `.sh` extension (although not necessary for the script to run) will allow you and everyone else to easily recognise it as a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

While for the most part, naming conventions like this don't really matter at all to Unix/Linux, the usual convention is for the "extensions" to be in the order of the steps used to create the file. So, for example, a file named `foo.tar.bz2.gpg.part01` would indicate a sequence of operations like the following:

1. Use `tar` to create `foo.tar`, which contains some other files
2. Use `bzip2` to compress `foo.tar` into `foo.tar.bz2`
3. Use `gnupg` to encrypt `foo.tar.bz2` into `foo.tar.bz2.gpg`
4. Use `split` or something similar to break the file into chunks for transmission/storage, resulting in one or more `foo.tar.bz2.gpg.part*` files.

The naming conventions are mostly just for human semantic meaning, though, and there's nothing stopping you from doing exactly the opposite, or even something completely random, except your own ability to remember exactly what you did...